# Grunt copy portion of files

Tags: gruntjs

I want to recursively copy portions of files to a destination. For instance, if the below was my file structure and I have 10 files like so

```
/*
  blah 
  blah 
  blah
  blah
  blah 
*/

Several 
lines 
of 
code 
here
```

I want to retrieve the portion in between the begin and end comment tags.

I have tried the following

1. Grunt-text-replace / grunt-regex-replace - I am able to select my pattern and replace things within the pattern but am not able to return the pattern alone. It returns the entire content.
2. Grunt copy-part-of-a-file - There's actually a plugin that does just this but it doesn't work and keeps giving me an error saying I have to give it input (which I have already provided)
3. Grunt copy plugin with process option will again allow me to replace portions of text but doesn't allow me to pick out just the comments alone.

Comment: show your grunt-config from try number 2, that should be the right way to do it. otherwise just write the plugin, it's easy to do so... (use grunt-init gruntplugin!)

Comment: I took your advice and tried it. You're right.. It was easy peasy to get it done! Thank you :)